# What is the Vedic definition of "life"?

Tags: vedas, life, guru

I'm wondering what is the definition of life from the Vedic perspective. What kind of relation does life have with God? Life has so many perspectives that you can't define life I guess. For me, life is a perfect guru who teaches without words. And if you don't follow life's teachings it will slowly go away. I can't describe with words what I feel when I think about the word "life" so I'm turning here for help.

Is it OK to serve life like you would serve your guru? To help and support life so that it can flourish like a sun. Is this a reliable way to attain God?

Comment: Indeed life is one of the greatest Guru! You have got the point very well. it's not about what you do on the outside. Its about who you are on the inside. A fish will be a fish even if it is trying to fly. And you are always Divine, whether you are leading a normal life or not! All austerities and all sadhana is done to purify the Heart, where you realize that 'All work is God's work, all life is God!'. All that you do WITH LOVE is Divine and is the Highest Meditation! Good question sir.

Answer (score 1):

The universe is made of *Jeev* or the soul, *Ishwar*, or god and *Maya* or illusion. The *Jeev* doesn't die, and is shapeless and formless. The *Jeev* is situated inside the body, or *Maya*, which is equal to a man putting on clothes. When you die, only the physical body dies, while the *Jeev* takes on another body, which can be of an animal, micro-organism, plant ect. The purpose of life is to serve god, and when god is served, *Jeev* can attain salvation, and spend the rest of eternity with *Ishwar*.

Comment: But  according to the Vedas, the Absolute, called Brahman, was present in everything, be it living or Nonliving, and thus everything is, as believers in the Vedas believe, 'endowed with sentience'. Thus, by this view, a piece of rock also have got' sentience '. But rock is truly Not a living thing. It seems the sages of Vedic times did Not have any concept of life.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try - Life is an expression of Consciousness, which is like the ocean in which waves rise and crash. Life is that wave which identifies itself as that wave, but in fact it is the ocean itself. Essentially, Life is a journey just like how the water from the ocean evaporates, becomes vapour, forms cloud, becomes snow, becomes melting water, becomes a river only to flow back and merge  into the ocean where it came from. In all of this, if at any one point, the realization dawns of one's real nature, the struggle eases. It is made easier through consistent remembrance of one's true nature through whichever sadhana one chooses. To be anything, anywhere then comes naturally, out of a sense of compassion. Getting this full realization could happen here and now or a few lifetimes, through self effort, level of thirst and Grace. To treat this life, this moment as a gift is the best way forward. You have chosen it as a Guru which is a wonderful thought. Serve it well to always remain rooted in the thought of discovering your real nature, which we have heard of, yet ignorant of. We are all in this journey to transcend this cycle or even if we have to be in it, we hope to be conscious of it to give our best for all that surrounds us.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).